# PHPMAILER form validation in php

Tags: php

I have a contact us page and I need to send an email using PHPMAILER when all the fields are filled. I have this code for the validation:

```
$msg = "";
$msg_2 = "";
$msg_3 = "";
$msg_4 = "";
if(empty($_POST['email_subject'])){
    $msg = "<span class='text-danger'>Please select a subject for your email.</span>";
}

if(empty($_POST['message'])){
    $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter your message.</span>";
}

if(empty($_POST['email_2'])){
    $msg_4 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>";
}

if($mail->Send()) {
    header('Location: thankYou_2.php');
}
```

I have three fields must be filled. Now, if the user has entered the email address and the message without the email subject the form is passed and will send an email. But if the user entered email address and email subject without message the form will not pass and the error message will display. I need to make the user MUST fill all fields and then send the email.

Comment: Having fixed the indentation, do you see that you are not doing ANY checks that an error has happened before sending the email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this will be sent regardless. You need to check if there is an error. Below would probably be a pretty easy way to do so.

```
$error = false;
if(empty($_POST['email_subject'])){
    $error = true;
    $msg = "<span class='text-danger'>Please select a subject for your email. 
</span>";
}

if(empty($_POST['message'])){
    $error = true;
    $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter your message.</span>";
}

if(empty($_POST['email_2'])){
    $error = true;
    $msg_4 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>";
}

if($error===false) {
    $mail->Send();
    header('Location: thankYou_2.php');
}
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

**JD Simpkins** anser is useful. Also you can use **if / else if** statement:

```
if(!isset($_POST['email_subject']) || empty($_POST['email_subject'])){
  $msg = "<span class='text-danger'>Please select a subject for your email.</span>";
}
else if(!isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])){
  $msg_2 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter your message.</span>";
}
else if(!isset($_POST['email_2']) || empty($_POST['email_2'])){
  $msg_4 = "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>";
}
else if($mail->Send()) {
  header('Location: thankYou_2.php');
}
```